# How to migrate reports (RDL files) from SQL Server 2008 R2 to 2012?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

We have a SQL Server 2008 R2 Server with Reporting Services with more than 200 reports.

For migration purpose we have installed SQL Server 2012 with Reporting Services on a new server. We have published the same RDL reports to this new server and we have terrible performance results. The reports are working but takes about 10times longer than with SQL Server 2008 R2.

We think that these performance troubles can be caused by the fact that the rdl files are 2008 R2 based.

How can we migrate these reports to SQL Server 2012 ? and/or how can we troubleshoot these performance problems ?

[UPDATE] After some investigations, I've found that my performance problem is not related with the reports.
The reports are generated from an asp.net application thanks to a call to the Render2 method of the reportexecution2005.asmx Web Service.
If I call the method from my production front web server the call takes more than 1 minute, if I call the exact same method from the same web service hosted on the same reporting services from my dev machine, the call takes few seconds.
That's very, very, very weird.

Any ideas about this behavior ?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

From: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143674(v=sql.110).aspx

> Reports are not upgraded when you upload a report definition file
> directly to the report server or SharePoint site. Upgrading a report
> definition in SQL Server Data Tools is the only way to upgrade the
> .rdl file.

In order to upgrade them, you need to:

> Report definition (.rdl) files are automatically upgraded in the
> following ways:
>
> When you open a report in Report Designer in SQL
> Server Data Tools (SSDT), the report definition is upgraded to the
> currently supported RDL schema. When you specify a SQL Server 2008 or
> SQL Server 2008 R2 report server in the project properties, the report
> definition is saved in a schema that is compatible with the target
> server.
>
> When you upgrade a Reporting Services installation to a SQL
> Server 2012 Reporting Services (SSRS) installation, existing reports
> and snapshots that have been published to a report server are compiled
> and automatically upgraded to the new schema the first time they are
> processed. If a report cannot be automatically upgraded, the report is
> processed using the backward-compatibility mode. The report definition
> remains in the original schema.

Comment: So it means that reports are OK but we have huge performance problems. Do you have any ideas about how to troubleshoot these problems ?

Comment: Pull out the queries from the the reports and run them in SSMS with Execution plan on.